# line plot representing two response variables

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze a dataset where there are two response variables X and Y for each treatment for each replication:

```
Treatment   Rep X   Y
N1  1 10.18 14.38
N1  2 13.53 14.38
N2  1 15.34 18.28
N2  2 10.4  7.14
N3  1 8.57  22.57
N3  2 13.95 19.9
N4  1 16.69 NA
N4  2 14.33 9.32
N5  1 NA    NA
N5  2 15.74 15.39
```

I want to calculate mean, sd and se values for each treatment for each response variable. Then I want to make a line plot with Treatment on x-axis; and two lines each for X and Y with confidence interval error bars.

I have used this to calculate and plot:

```
df<-Data1 %>%
  group_by(Treatment, Rep) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), list(mean = ~mean(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE), 
                                         sd = ~sd(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE),
                                         se= ~sd(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(n()))) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(mean:se), mean, na.rm = TRUE)


p<- ggplot(data=na.omit(df),aes(reorder(Treatment, mean, sum), mean, group = 1))+
  geom_line(stat = "identity", colour="black", width = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=Line, ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se),
                width = 0.25, color = "black") + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 40)) + theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 5.5, angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = "black",face = "bold")) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size= 8, hjust = 1, colour = "black",face = "bold"))
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please show your best attempt at coding this.

Comment: I have added in the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
Data1 = structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5"), class = "factor"), 
    Rep = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), X = c(10.18, 
    13.53, 15.34, 10.4, 8.57, 13.95, 16.69, 14.33, NA, 15.74), 
    Y = c(14.38, 14.38, 18.28, 7.14, 22.57, 19.9, NA, 9.32, NA, 
    15.39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Define function to calculate sem:

```
SE = function(x){
  x=x[!is.na(x)]
  sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
}
```

Load libraries and pivot the table to longer, then calculate mean and sem for each response in each treatment:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df<-Data1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Treatment,Rep)) %>% 
  group_by(Treatment,name) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(value,na.rm=TRUE),SE=SE(value))
```

When you do `group_by`,the grouping variables are not included in summarize, so you don't need `summarise_at`. Also you cannot include Rep in grouping because this will make the grouping into by observation, which is wrong.

Now we plot:

```
p<- ggplot(df,aes(x=Treatment,y=mean,colour=name))+
geom_line(aes(group=name)) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-SE, ymax = mean+SE),
                width = 0.25) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 40)) + 
theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size= 5.5, 
angle = 45, hjust = 1, colour = "black",face = "bold")) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size= 8, hjust = 1, 
 colour = "black",face = "bold"))
```

Hopefully this is what you want.. If not, please elaborate more in your question.

[image]